# How to properly type-annotate an Axios request?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I have an API for which I created type annotations for all endpoints using [openapi-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript).

Now, I want to annotate my Axios requests with this information.

Take the following bit of code, part of a Vue.js project I've been working on:

```
type FactRepeater = components['schemas']['FactRepeater'];
type FactRepeaterResponse =
  paths['/api/v1/repeaters/fact-repeater/']['get']['responses']['200']['content']['application/json'];
type FactRepeaterRequest =
  paths['/api/v1/repeaters/fact-repeater/']['get']['parameters']['query'];

const repeaters: Ref<Array<FactRepeater>> = ref([]);

async function requestRepeaters(
  limit: number,
  offset: number,
  ordering: string | null = null,
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const response: AxiosResponse<FactRepeaterResponse, FactRepeaterRequest> =
      await api.get('/api/v1/repeaters/fact-repeater/', {
        params: { limit, offset, ordering },
      });
    // These fields aren't null because this only happens on success
    repeaters.value = response.data.results!;
    pagination.value.rowsNumber = response.data.count!;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

The relevant parts of the `components` schema:

```
// ...
    // components["schemas"]
    FactRepeater: {
      id: number;
      // ...
    };
// ...
    PaginatedFactRepeaterList: {
      count?: number;
      next?: string | null;
      previous?: string | null;
      results?: components["schemas"]["FactRepeater"][];
    };
// ...
    // paths['/api/v1/repeaters/fact-repeater/']['get']
    responses: {
      200: {
        content: {
          "application/json": components["schemas"]["PaginatedFactRepeaterList"];
        };
      };
    };
    parameters: {
      query?: {
        ordering?: string;
        limit?: number;
        offset?: number;
        // ...
      };
    };
// ...
```

However, the code isn't providing a good enough description of types. For example, according to my IDE, when I hover over `params`:

[image: Missing types for params]

I thought this was supposed to be inside the information provided by filling in `AxiosResponse`, but apparently not.

What changes do I need to make?

Follow-up question: When an endpoint doesn't have any configurable request parameters, just an endpoint, how do write the request type for the `AxiosResponse`?

Comment: Axios' typing look pretty inflexible in this regard. The second type argument of `AxiosResponse` doesn't type `params`, it types the request body. Type of `params` comes from `AxiosRequestConfig` which just says `params?: any` and doesn't provide any way to override it with a generic or something. So the obvious suggestion is to create your own wrapper for `get`, `post`, etc. methods with an extra type argument for `params` hints. Looks like `axios` doesn't quite have an elegant way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Axios is not very configurable sadly. You can't even customize the response type without setting the first generic type of request functions as unknown, if you have used any response interceptors. That's why I like to override it baldly with my own typing system, that will allow more customization.

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

type CustomAxiosRequestConfig<T> = Omit<AxiosRequestConfig, 'params'> & {params: T};
type CustomInstancePromises = {
  get<T, U>(url: string, config?: CustomAxiosRequestConfig<U>): Promise<T>;
  post<T, U>(url: string, data?: unknown, config?: CustomAxiosRequestConfig<U>): Promise<T>;
  put<T, U>(url: string, data?: unknown, config?: CustomAxiosRequestConfig<U>): Promise<T>;
  patch<T, U>(url: string, data?: unknown, config?: CustomAxiosRequestConfig<U>): Promise<T>;
  delete<T, U>(url: string, config?: CustomAxiosRequestConfig<U>): Promise<T>;
};

type AxiosInstanceType = CustomInstancePromises & AxiosInstance;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL
}) as AxiosInstanceType;

// example:
axiosInstance.get<ResponseType, ParamsObjectType>(url, {params: {...}); // params will be inferred properly
```

The first generic type will be your response type (without having to write `<unknown, PostInterceptedShape>`), and the second generic type will replace the params: any in Axios's typing system with your own params type. You can further customize its type system this way. It's not the best but they don't provide a better way to do this.

Also you can't use interface for the `AxiosInstanceType` because `extends` will give you error and in order to override it must be with type intersection